# Каталог сотрудников для интранет сайта с загрузкой данных из AD

Tags: cms

Подскажите готовый модуль каталога сотрудников для интранет сайта с получением данных из Active Directory. Рассматривается любая платформа, кроме Bitrix и Sharepoint. Желательно Open Source.

Comment: А что нужно то? я например набросал подобный функционал на NodeJS с вэб мордой, там делов то на пару дней, делал с помощью ldapjs

Comment: Задача распространенная, надеялся найти модуль для CMS.